# Exclude negative results from mySql query

Tags: mysql

I'd like exclude negative results from a mySql query.
This is my query:

```
SELECT
MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) AS days,
date_ship
FROM table

+------------+------+
| date_ship  | days |
+------------+------+
| 2019-07-15 |   -6 |
| 2019-07-12 |   -3 |
| 2019-07-01 |    9 |
| 2019-06-25 |   14 |
+------------+------+
```

I'd like get only negative results:

```
+------------+------+
| date_ship  | days |
+------------+------+
| 2019-07-15 |   -6 |
| 2019-07-12 |   -3 |
+------------+------+
```

Comment: That's not really 'excluding' then, is it!?!?

Comment: This SQL is malformed (it lacks `GROUP BY`). MySQL 5.7.4 and older used to allow this.

Comment: Please note that you can [edit] your question in order to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out here in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953676/exclude-negative-results-from-mysql-query/56953709?noredirect=1#comment100445799_56953676), your query should probably essentially be:

```
SELECT
  MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) AS days,
  date_ship
FROM table
GROUP BY date_ship
HAVING MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) < 0
;
```

Comment: Tip. Use `HAVING`.

Comment: You might consider deleting the first half of this answer.

Comment: Why are you grouping? What happens if he wants to keep the duplicates because he has more columns in his table? The PO didn't say anything about grouping, so maybe tis is not aright answer even if it works

Comment: works fine but with >  HAVING MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) > 0

@nacho Yes I not need to use Group by

Comment: @cloude Sure but then your expected result is misleading.

Comment: If you don't need to use group by, this is an incorrect answer. If you have 2 rows with the same date_ship, with this answer you will get only one row result

Comment: @nacho Yes is a problem, because I need all rows with same date_ship.
I resolved with GROUP BY on "id_ship" field.  is a good way?

Comment: I would need to see your table structure to say if it is ok, but i think is not a good way. If you upload your table structure i can tell. Anyway, the answer you have from Arunkumar seems a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the below query and try it.

```
SELECT MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) AS days,
date_ship
FROM table WHERE MAX(datediff(now(), date_ship)) < 0;
```

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY`. Then, place the condition in a `HAVING` clause.